# HTMLworker is printing style tag contents on the top of the generated pdf

Tags: java, itext, html-to-pdf, xdoc

I am trying to read a docx file into html using XdocReport and convert that html into pdf using htmlworker. It all works fine and I can see that the styling part is also OK in the final pdf.

The only issue is that the contents of the style tag are showing up on the top of the pdf. How do I resolve this ?

FYI...I tried XMLWorker also but it is generating a blank pdf.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
p{margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:1pt;}p.Normal{margin-bottom:0.0pt;}span.Normal{font-size:12.0pt;}p.TableGrid{margin-bottom:0.0pt;}span.XDocReport_Hyperlink{color:#0000ff;text-decoration:underline;}p.XDocReport_Heading_1{margin-top:24.0pt;margin-bottom:0.0pt;}span.XDocReport_Heading_1{font-family:'Calibri Light';font-size:14.0pt;font-weight:bold;color:#365f91;}p.XDocReport_Heading_2{margin-top:10.0pt;margin-bottom:0.0pt;}span.XDocReport_Heading_2{font-family:'Calibri Light';font-size:13.0pt;font-weight:bold;color:#4f81bd;}p.XDocReport_Heading_3{margin-top:10.0pt;margin-bottom:0.0pt;}span.XDocReport_Heading_3{font-family:'Calibri Light';font-weight:bold;color:#4f81bd;}p.XDocReport_Heading_4{margin-top:10.0pt;margin-bottom:0.0pt;}span.XDocReport_Heading_4{font-family:'Calibri Light';font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;color:#4f81bd;}p.XDocReport_Heading_5{margin-top:10.0pt;margin-bottom:0.0pt;}span.XDocReport_Heading_5{font-family:'Calibri Light';color:#243f60;}p.XDocReport_Heading_6{margin-top:10.0pt;margin-bottom:0.0pt;}span.XDocReport_Heading_6{font-family:'Calibri Light';font-style:italic;color:#243f60;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
// some content
</body>
</html>
```

Output
[image: Generated pdf]

Itext Version - 2.1.7

Code

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\pp.pdf"));
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file); 
document.open();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(s)); // s has the entire html
document.close();
```

Once again, the converted pdf looks good with all formatting retained. The only issue is with the style contents showing up on the top.

Comment: `HTMLWorker` support for html is very limited. If you want to use it, keep your html very simple and old fashioned.

Comment: Thanks mkl for letting me know. Which other open source library can I use for this conversion from html to pdf ?

Comment: *"Which other open source library can I use for this conversion from html to pdf"* - You should make that a question on the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can use iText 7 with the pdfHTML add-on. Is an answer I would give on the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.